# Che cos'è un "cannone di meliga"?

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Purtroppo quella sera finí malamente per me, e non per colpa di lei, ma tutta di Jano che quando finimmo di spogliare e ci mettemmo a cantare e a far gli scherzi, si ficcò un **cannone di meliga** in mezzo alle gambe e saltando come un montone perseguitò Fede per cinque minuti finché lei dovette chiamare aiuto alla padrona.

Qualcuno di voi mi sa spiegare cos'è un "cannone di meliga"? Ho cercato alla voce "cannone" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente che abbia senso nel contesto della frase sopra citata. Il significato di "meliga" l'ho trovato nel [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/melica2/):

> nell’Italia settentr., anche altro nome del *mais*: *tutti avevano più caro non vederseli sull’aia, neanche per aiutare a spogliar la meliga* (Fenoglio).

Comment: Secondo questo [sito web](http://dialetticon.blogspot.com/2009/07/formenton.html?m=1) il "canù dèl melgòt" in bergamasco è il torsolo della pannocchia sgranata. La traduzione letterale di "canù" sarebbe "cannone".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dal contesto mi pare che per cannone di meliga si intenda la pannocchia sgranata, utilizzata per simulare il membro maschile ed inseguire Fede.

In altre zone del basso Piemonte il termine meliga, per indicare il mais, ha le varianti [melia o meria](http://www.lastampa.it/2013/09/20/societa/il-piemonte-in-un-frollino-TQx4RUoLnIzQXM7yCM2VXN/pagina.html).

> mélia (s. f.). granoturco, formentone.

In dialetto piemontese esistono anche i

> canunsén (s. m. pl.). cialdoni, sottilissime faldelle di pasta, cotte
>   come le ostie in forno appropriato e rattorte a guisa di barba o di
>   cartoccio.

che si possono tradurre in italiano con il termine cannoni.

Comment: Non sarebbe la pannocchia sgranata secondo spiega il link che ho messo nel mio commento precedente? (è bergamasco, ma immagino che nel dialetto delle Langhe sia qualcosa di simile).

Comment: Infatti, mi ero perso il libro link nel commento.